# I want to call model in modules folder in autoload file

Tags: codeigniter

Here I want to call birthday_model in autoload but I am getting error in that.

```
Unable to locate the model you have specified: birthday_model
```

My folder structure is:

```
modules/birthday/model/birthday_model
```

Autoload:

```
$autoload['model'] = array('HookModel','AppModel','Birthday_model');
```

birthday_model:

```
class Birthday_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
}
```

Here I want to call birthday_model in other controller of "dailyattendance",

```
modules/dailyattendance/dailyattendance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

`$autoload['model'] = array('HookModel','AppModel','birthday/model/Birthday_model');`

Answer (score 0):

Change your model name "birthday_model" to "Birthday_model".